# How to reverse the index value in Python using for loop with a given list

Tags: python, loops

I want to create a function that prints out a tic-tac-toe board with a given list that position its index value on the board in a reverse order like on a number keyboard that is from 9 to 1, with the 1st row having the index value of 7, 8, 9: 2nd row 4, 5, 6: 3rd row 1, 2, 3.

For example: a given list

`test_board = ['O','O','X','X','X','O','X','O','X']`

That show print out like this:

```
 X | O | X 
---|---|---
 X | X | O 
---|---|---
 O | O | X
```

I wrote this function:

```
def display_board(board):

    h_sep = '-' * 3
    for i in range(3):

        for j in reversed(board[1:]):

            print(f"{j:^3}|{j:^3}|{j:^3}")

        if i != 2:
            print(f"{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}")
```

But i get this print out when i call the function with the given list:

```
test_board = ['O','O','X','X','X','O','X','O','X']
display_board(test_board)
```

Output:

```
 X | X | X 
 O | O | O 
 X | X | X 
 O | O | O 
 X | X | X 
 X | X | X 
 X | X | X 
 O | O | O 
---|---|---
 X | X | X 
 O | O | O 
 X | X | X 
 O | O | O 
 X | X | X 
 X | X | X 
 X | X | X 
 O | O | O 
---|---|---
 X | X | X 
 O | O | O 
 X | X | X 
 O | O | O 
 X | X | X 
 X | X | X 
 X | X | X 
 O | O | O
```

Edited:
Can i use `for loop` to achieve this without writing multiple print statement like this:

```
print(f"{board[6]:^3}|{board[7]:^3}|{board[8]:^3}")
print(f"{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}")
print(f"{board[3]:^3}|{board[4]:^3}|{board[5]:^3}")
print(f"{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}")
print(f"{board[0]:^3}|{board[1]:^3}|{board[2]:^3}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second for you are printing it 3 times before going to the next line.

Your function with the following modifications would work for your problem:

```
def display_board(board):
h_sep = '-' * 3
for i in reversed(range(3)):

    print(f"{board[i*3]:^3}|{board[i*3+1]:^3}|{board[i*3+2]:^3}")

    if i != 0:
        print(f"{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `iter` to achieve this.

**Solution**

```
def display_board(board):
    h_sep = '-' * 3
    it = iter(reversed(board))
    count = 0
    for j in it:
        print(f"{j:^3}|{next(it):^3}|{next(it):^3}")
        if count < 2: 
            print(f"{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}")
            count+=1

test_board = ['X','O','O','O','X','X','X','O','X']
display_board(test_board)
```

Just to visualize the result, I used numbers in your `test_board`:

```
def display_board(board):
    h_sep = '-' * 3
    it = iter(reversed(board))
    for j in it:
        print(f"{int(j)-2:^3}|{int(next(it)):^3}|{int(next(it))+2:^3}")
        if int(j) > 3: print(f"{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}")

test_board = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
display_board(test_board)
```

OUT:

```
 7 | 8 | 9 
---|---|---
 4 | 5 | 6
---|---|---
 1 | 2 | 3
```

Comment: Oh this is great, I'm not familiar with iter() function yet, i will look into it, but i want to write an if condition which doesn't print the last `print(f"{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}")` when the iteration ends, i did this `if next(it)[] != len(board):
            print(f"{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}|{h_sep:^3}")` but i don't know how to return the index number of the `next(it)` to compare with  the` len(board)`

Comment: It work perfectly with numbers, but not with strings like my list `['O','O','X','X','X','O','X','O','X']` i get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'X'
`

Comment: @KwameBenqazy I added the solution separately, this was merely to visualize if the order is important. It probably makes sense to have generate the list in the right order that you want in that case (X,O,O,O,X,X,XO,X)

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to insert the vertical lines and then loop in reverse order.

```
test_board = ['O','O','X','X','X','O','X','O','X']

for i in range(3,-1,-1):
    li=test_board[i*3:(i+1)*3]
    print('|'.join(li))
    if 0<i<3: print('-'*5)
```

Answer (score 0):

a longer version of the solution that can handle size of board greater than 3

```
    def display_board(board, size=3):
        parts = []
        h_seps = []
        for i in range(size):
            begin = i * size
            end = begin + size
            parts.append(board[begin:end])
            h_seps.append("-" * 3)

        first = True
        while len(parts) > 0:
            part = parts.pop()

            if first is False:
                print("|".join(h_seps))

            first = False
            print(" " + " | ".join(part))

    display_board(["O", "O", "X", "X", "X", "O", "X", "O", "X"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want pythonic-one-liner, then here you go

```
def display_board(board):
    def display_board(board):
        for i in range(3,-1,-1): print(' | '.join(board[i*3:(i+1)*3]),'\n--|---|---' if 0 < i < 3 else '' )

test_board = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
display_board(test_board)
```