# How to write a function with a for loop to check tic tac toe wins

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a function with a `for loop` that checks for wining combination for a tic tac toe game based on a given list (board) and a marker ('X','O').

I was able to achieve this for the row wins with this `for loop` statement

```
def win_check(board, mark):
    # Win tic tac toe?

    board = board[1:]

    # ALL ROWS, and check to see if they all share the same marker?
    # i used `for loop` to achieve the row wins check. 
    # But if there is another way to achieve it with this `r_win = [[9,8,7],[6,5,4],[3,2,1]]`

    # This works fine for the row checks
    for i in reversed(range(3)):
        if board[i*3] in mark and board[i*3+1] in mark and board[i*3+2] in mark:
            return True
    else:
        return False


    # ALL COLUMNS, check to see if marker matches

    c_win = [[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3]] # i created this list if it can be used to make check for column wins. 

    for i in c_win:
        # if statement goes here to check columns wins 
            return True # and return true if there is a match 
    else:
        return False


    # 2 diagonals, check to see match
    d_win = [[9,5,1],[7,5,3]] # i created this list if it can be used to make check for diagonal wins. 

    for i in d_win:
        # if statement goes here to check diagonal wins 
            return True # and return true if there is a match 
    else:
        return False
```

example function call

`test_board = ['#','X','O','X','X','X','X','O','X','X']`

`win_check(test_board,'X')`

Comment: Does your board `test_board = ['#','X','O','X','X','X','X','O','X','X']` mean `X O X \n X X X \n O X X`?

Comment: @EricJin No it is a list for the board game [this is what I'm working on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62104582/how-to-reverse-the-index-value-in-python-using-for-loop-with-a-given-list)

Comment: Oh, so it goes like 789/456/123. Got it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it more pythonish:

```py
def win_check(board, mark):
    board_=[el==mark for el in board]
    if(any([
        all(board_[1:4]),
        all(board_[4:7]),
        all(board_[7:10]),
        all(board_[slice(1,8,3)]),
        all(board_[slice(2,9,3)]),
        all(board_[slice(3,10,3)]),
        all(board_[slice(1,10,4)]),
        all(board_[slice(3,8,2)])
    ])):
        return True
    return False
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> test_board = ['#','X','O','X','X','X','X','O','X','X']
>>> print(win_check(test_board,'X'))

True
```

Comment: Good spot - `slice(start, stop, step)` doesn't include `stop` - I corrected other 4 as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For this case, use `'X'` for a space occupied by X, `'O'` for a space occupied by O, and `None` for an empty space.

```py
def test_equal(index1, index2, index3):
    if index1 is not None and index1 == index2 and index2 == index3:
        return index1 # either 'X' or 'O'
    else:
        return False

def get_winner(board):
    '''Test for win, where board is a :list: [7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]'''
    b1, b2, b3 = board[6:]
    b4, b5, b6 = board[3:6]
    b7, b8, b9 = board[:3]
    wins = (
        test_equal(b1, b2, b3),
        test_equal(b4, b5, b6),
        test_equal(b7, b8, b9),
        test_equal(b1, b4, b7),
        test_equal(b2, b5, b8),
        test_equal(b3, b6, b9),
        test_equal(b1, b5, b9),
        test_equal(b3, b5, b7)
        )
    return 'X' if 'X' in wins else ('O' if 'O' in wins else False)
```

Function `get_winner()` will return `'X'` if X is the winner (or both sides win, but that should not be a problem as you should be checking for a winner every turn), `'O'` if O is the winner, and `False` if nobody wins. The code I wrote is case sensitive, so `'x'` or `'o'` won't work!

Here is sample output:

```py
>>> x = 'X'
>>> o = 'O'
>>> n = None
>>> get_winner((x,x,x, n,n,n, n,o,o))
'X'
>>> get_winner((x,n,n, o,x,o, o,o,x))
'X'
>>> get_winner((x,x,n, x,x,n, o,o,o))
'O'
>>> get_winner((x,o,o, x,o,o, n,x,n))
False
>>>
```